# Set priority for custom fields on woocommerce product tabs

Tags: woocommerce, tabs, custom-fields

I want to add two custom fields to the general data tab when a product is simple.
However, i want these custom fields to appear on top of the list.

I have tried setting priority in the hook, but that doesnt work.

So what i have is the following:

```
function add_options_simple() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $product = wc_get_product($id)->get_type();
    if ($product == 'simple'){
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_brand',
            'label'       => 'Brand',
            'type'        => 'text',
        )
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_EAN',
            'label'       => 'EAN:',
            'type'        => 'text',
        )
    );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_options_simple',1,3 );
```

But no success.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This hook is loading after woo default fields so no i dont think so unless you hardcode it. Another option is to create custom tab where you can set priority and your tab will be first with your fields.

Comment: Displaying at the very top is not possible, as this is not provided in WooCommerce (unless you are going to edit core files which is strongly discouraged or use 'dirty solutions'). To apply this the WooCommerce way: you can display a custom field right after the sales price field, there is the first possibility to add a field between/after the existing fields on the product general tab for simple products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add those fields to the top. as you can see [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-general.php#L39)

But you can try with jQuery. try the below code.

```
function add_options_simple() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $product = wc_get_product($id)->get_type();
    if ($product == 'simple'){ ?>
        <div class="options_group brand_ean show_if_simple hidden">
            <?php
            woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                array(
                    'id'          => '_brand',
                    'label'       => 'Brand',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                )
            );
            woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                array(
                    'id'          => '_EAN',
                    'label'       => 'EAN:',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                )
            ); 
           ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var brand_ean = jQuery('.brand_ean')[0].outerHTML;
            jQuery('.brand_ean').remove();
            jQuery( brand_ean ).insertBefore('.options_group.pricing');
        </script>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_options_simple', 1, 3 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: This is correct, but it is not how i wanted to solve it. However, your link to the core file is pretty clear: first the boxes are generated, then follows the add_action. So that makes it impossible clearly. Thanks

Comment: I know this the not what you want but I find it only this way.