# How to add a button or field to backend woocommerce variation product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I have a product with some variations on it. I need to add a button to every variation just on the place marked with red square you can see on the image below. Right next to or below original "Select image" button.
[image: I want the button there]

I already tried some hooks for it but I can't find the right one. I tried "woocommerce_variation_options_pricing" and some similar ones but I managed to place button a little bit lower than I wanted. Just like on a screen given below.

[image: I managed to place the button here]

Is there any woocommerce hook I can use to achieve the position I want?

Comment: There is no hook provided for this so you should actually modify the core file. However, this is strongly discouraged!! Another way is through a 'dirty workaround', see [this similar question + my comment + the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69738966/11987538)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is no hook provided and it is not possible to add some elements in such a place with no "dirty workarounds". I think I am going to deal with the lower place.
Thanks for help [@7uc1f3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11987538/7uc1f3r)